# call the form_load() function on closing a child form

Tags: c#

I am creating an app which currently has 3 forms,

- Parent form - to accept login details from the user, validate and if successful hides itself and opens a  child form.
- 1st Child form - on form load connects to the database fetches data and displays it. Click on new entry and another child form opens.
- 2nd child form - user enters new data for new entry in the database, on success a success message box comes up. user then may click on close button and this form hides itself and the 1st Child form is shown.

what i want to do is to find out someway to reload the 1st Child form, on closing thee 2nd Child form. This will result in the records being displayed in it to get refreshed and thus show the new entry that was just made using the 2nd Child form.

Please  guide me as to how i can achieve this.

Here is the code that i used to handle the hide events.

In the main form on login event = true

```
cpanel child = new cpanel(); //create new isntance of form, cpanel is the 1st child form
child.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(child_FormClosed); //add handler to catch when child form is closed
child.Show(); //show child
this.Hide(); //hide parent

void child_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            //when child form is closed, the parent reappears
            MessageBox.Show("You have been logged out.");
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

In the 2nd child form i have something like this

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok once again i have finally solved the problem, and is posting the solution in hopes it will someday help someone with similar problem.

The actual solution is very simple really, here is what needed to be done.

add this line in the child form, somewhere in the protected section of 2nd Form other than inside a method so that it is always present.

```
cpanel child = new cpanel();
```

inside the close button method of the 2nd Form needs to be something like this.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            child.Show();
            this.Hide(); //hide parent
        }
```

This will enable you to get an updated 1st Form when you click on the Close button of the 2nd Form after updating the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `ChildForm1` to be main form:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

using(var loginForm = new LoginForm())
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        return;

Application.Run(new ChildForm1());
```

And show `ChildFrom2` from `ChildForm1` form:

```
Hide(); // you really don't need to hide main form

using(var childForm2 = new ChildForm2())
{
    if (childForm2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // update ChildForm1 with data from ChildForm2
    }    
}

Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this :**

In  2nd Child form before closing:

```
childForm1.refresh()
```

In 1st Child form:

```
public static void refresh() //You can use it with parameters too
{
  //do something
}
```